# Ansible getting error running a Windows "dir" command?

Tags: ansible

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.10.8
```

I have a simple task to list the `*.zip` file in a Windows folder

```
- name: Get name of old file
  win_command: dir /b *.zip
  args:
    chdir C:\\temp
```

and I get

```
TASK [list-files : Get name of old file] ******************************************
fatal: [10.x.x.x]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "dir /b *.zip", "msg": "Exception calling \"SearchPath\" with \"1\" argument(s): \"Could not find file 'dir.exe'.\"", "rc": 2}
```

However, this works

```
ansible -i 10.x.x.x, 10.x.x.x -m win_command -a "cmd.exe /c dir c:\temp\*.zip"
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*FAIR WARNING: I don't have a copy of Windows to test this, but still hope it's helpful...*

Since `dir` is (as the error helpfully explains) not an executable but rather a shell built-in, you'll want to use [`win_shell:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/collections/ansible/windows/win_shell_module.html) instead of the `command` version

As the fine manual points out, the default shell is PowerShell, so ensure you provide the [`executable: cmd`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/collections/ansible/windows/win_shell_module.html#parameter-executable) to put it back to the old one if you really want to use that DOS style invocation versus [`Get-ChildItem -Recursive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-files-and-folders?view=powershell-7.2)

```yaml
- name: Get name of old file
  win_shell: dir /b *.zip
  args:
    executable: cmd
    chdir: C:\\temp
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked., though I 'm still curious why my original task didn't work.

Comment: It's the difference between [`system()`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man3/system.3.html) and [`exec()`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man3/exec.3.html) or whatever they're called in Windows: one version has an implied `cmd /c` wrapped around it, and the other is expected to **start** with a `.exe` or `.com` that the _kernel_ can execute, without the intermediate shell. As you observed, it's possible to emulate `system:` via `command: cmd /c "do something awesome"` because they're equivalent